# Save the last page of the book and load when the book is opened?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, adapter

I'm developing an app that will have some books, and I don't know how to save the last page opened of the book and open when the book is opened, even if the app closed. I don't use fragments, just a `CustomSwipeAdapter`, `ImageViewTouchViewPager` and `ViewPager`.

Everything works fine, I just need this, actually in `MainActivity` I can save the current position but I don't know how to set save to set when the book is opened to show the last page before the app was closed.

Thank you.

```
public class CustomSwipeAdapter1 extends PagerAdapter{    

private int[] pagesBookOne = {R.drawable.pageone, R.drawable.pagetwo, R.drawable.pagethree};
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

public CustomSwipeAdapter1(Context context){

        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return paginasLivroUm.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view == (LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_layout, container, false);
        ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = item_view.findViewById(R.id.imageviewtouch_xml);
        imageViewTouch.setImageResource(paginasLivroUm[position]);

        imageViewTouch.setDisplayType(ImageViewTouchBase.DisplayType.FIT_TO_SCREEN);

        container.addView(item_view);
        return item_view;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
        //super.destroyItem(container, position, object);

    }

}

==========================================================


import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class LivroUmActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ViewPager viewPager1;
    private CustomSwipeAdapter1 adapter1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_livro_um);


        viewPager1 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager1_xml);
        adapter1 = new CustomSwipeAdapter1(this);

        viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter1);



    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        positionSaved  = viewPager1.getCurrentItem();

       //Here I can save the position, just don't know how to set on the viewpager.
        super.onDestroy();
    }


}

==========================================================


import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouch;
import it.sephiroth.android.library.imagezoom.ImageViewTouchBase;


public class ImageViewTouchViewPager extends ViewPager{

    private static final String TAG = "ImageViewTouchViewPager";
    public static final String VIEW_PAGER_OBJECT_TAG = "image#";

    private int previousPosition;

    private OnPageSelectedListener onPageSelectedListener;

    public ImageViewTouchViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ImageViewTouchViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public void setOnPageSelectedListener(OnPageSelectedListener listener) {
        onPageSelectedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean canScroll(View v, boolean checkV, int dx, int x, int y) {
        if (v instanceof ImageViewTouch) {
            return ((ImageViewTouch) v).canScroll(dx);
        } else {
            return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
        }
    }

    public interface OnPageSelectedListener {

        public void onPageSelected(int position);

    }

    private void init() {
        previousPosition = getCurrentItem();

        setOnPageChangeListener(new SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (onPageSelectedListener != null) {
                    onPageSelectedListener.onPageSelected(position);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                if (state == SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING && previousPosition != getCurrentItem()) {
                    try {
                        ImageViewTouch imageViewTouch = (ImageViewTouch)
                                findViewWithTag(VIEW_PAGER_OBJECT_TAG + getCurrentItem());
                        if (imageViewTouch != null) {
                            imageViewTouch.zoomTo(1f, 300);
                        }

                        previousPosition = getCurrentItem();
                    } catch (ClassCastException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "This view pager should have only ImageViewTouch as a children.", ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the app is closed and opened again, you need to save the page number in a persistent storage. As it's just a number, you can use SharedPreference.

So have a key in SharedPreference like "pageNumber". And every time a new page is loaded, save the page number to "pageNumber". This way you don't need to worry about saving the last page number right before the app is closed.

When the app is opened again, check for the "pageNumber" and load that.

Comment: Thank your very much. Very well explained.

Comment: @djalmafreestyler Glad to help. If this solves your problem, kindly upvote/accept the answer.

Comment: Where do I use SharedPreferences, in the adapter or MainActivity?

Comment: @djalmafreestyler The ideal way is to do it in MainActivity. When the app opens you can fetch the pageNumber in MainActivity and pass it during Adapter creation. But you can do in Adapter as well. It's totally up to you.

Comment: Could you please give me an example how to set a position of an array of int in the viewpager? I tried this code after saved the value in SharedPreferences, but it's not getting the lastpage.                              SharedPreferences storePage1 = getPreferences(savedPage);
            int  lastPage = storePage1.getInt("savedPage", savedPage);
            viewPager1.setAdapter(adapter1);
            viewPager1.setCurrentItem(lastPage);

Answer (score 0):

You can refer:

- Use **Shared Preferences** to save last page of book when you close app
- When you open app, you can get last page and set postion with last page:

> viewPager.setCurrentItem(/** lastpage get from Shared Preferences */);

I hope it can help your problem!